# In React, I cannot display any content inside MUI Material's Modal

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I'm trying to display (In a basic To-Do app) a Box with a TextField and a Switch. Before I was trying to style the app with vanilla CSS, but I found myself way more comfortable and fast, using MUI. Before that, my map function was working: I would have click on the button, and a new Input with a Ceckbox would appear. Now that I'm trying to use the same logic and put the code inside MUI modal, but for some reason, I only display what's outside of the map function.

[enter image description here][1]

````
export default function CreateList({ createListHandler }) {

    const [title, setTitle] = useState("");
    const [notes, setNotes] = useState([]);
    const [createList, setCreateList] = useState(false);
    const [open, setOpen] = useState(false);

    const handleClose = () => setOpen(false);

    const navigate = useNavigate();

    const handleClick = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        setCreateList(true);
        setOpen(true);
    };

    const updateNote = (index, field, value) => {
        const newNotes = [...notes];
        newNotes[index][field] = value;
        setNotes(newNotes);
    };

    const addNote = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        const newNote = { text: "", completed: false };
        setNotes([...notes, newNote]);
    };


    const handleSubmit = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();

        const requestBody = {
            title,
            notes
        };

        axios
            .post(`${API_URL}/api/lists`, requestBody)
            .then((response) => {
                setTitle("");
                setNotes([]);

                navigate("/")
            })
            .catch((err) => console.log(err))
    };




    return (
        <div>
            <IconButton>

                <ChecklistOutlinedIcon
                    sx={{
                        color: "rgb(0, 0, 0, 1)"
                    }}
                    className="create-buttons" onClick={handleClick}></ChecklistOutlinedIcon></IconButton>
            <Modal
                aria-labelledby="transition-modal-title"
                aria-describedby="transition-modal-description"
                open={open}
                onClose={handleClose}
                closeAfterTransition
                slots={{ backdrop: Backdrop }}
                slotProps={{
                    backdrop: {
                        timeout: 500,
                    },
                }}
            >
                <Fade in={open}>
                    <Box sx={style}>
                        {
                            createList &&

                            <TextField onSubmit={handleSubmit}
                                id="outlined-multiline-flexible"
                                label="Title"
                                multiline
                                name="title"
                                value={title}
                            >


                                {notes.map((note, index) =>
                                    <Box key={index}>
                                        <TextField
                                            type="text"
                                            name="text"
                                            value={note.text}
                                            onChange={(e) => updateNote(index, "text", e.target.value)}>

                                        </TextField>
                                        <label>Completed</label>
                                        <Switch
                                            type="checkbox"
                                            name="completed"
                                            inputProps={{ 'aria-label': 'controlled' }}
                                            checked={note.completed}
                                            onChange={(e) => updateNote(index, "completed", e.target.checked)} />

                                    </Box>
                                )}
                                <IconButton>
                                    <AddTaskIcon className="create-buttons" onClick={addNote}></AddTaskIcon>
                                </IconButton>

                                <button type="submit">Save</button>
                            </TextField>
                        }
                    </Box>
                </Fade>
            </Modal>
        </div >
    );
}```


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/cVZR3.png
````

Comment: You're rendering the `notes` inside a `TextField` component I don't think that is something you want